# Possibility of "orphan removing" in many-to-one relationships?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

First of all, I am using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate underneath.
Let us imagine that we have two classes:
1. Person (int id, Address address, String fullName)
2. Address (int id, String country, String street).

I am manually persisting addresses to prevent redundancy.

How would I go about implementing orphan removing of Addresses ONLY when all the people using a certain address are removed? 
Cascading causes obvious constraint issues. Is that possible with Spring Data JPA + Hibernate, or do I need to implement my own lower-level logic for this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with JPA/Hibernate.

You have to handle the deletion of Addresses without Persons yourself.